# How to hide this startup page I am using calendly

Tags: wordpress, calendar, calendly

[image]
I am adding bookings to my website using calendly. when I configure all things using calendly and added to my website using elementor ( HTML element) then this page appears instead of the next page which Is the booking page.

Answer (score 1):

To embed a specific event type you can click on the event type's share button, then select "Add to website".

[image]